# regular expression tog et values of html tag attributes

Tags: php, regex

```
<li class="zk_list_c2 f_l"><a title="abc" target="_blank" href="link">
                                        abc
                                    </a>&nbsp;</li>
```

how would i extract abc and link?

```
$pattern="/<li class=\"zk_list_c2 f_l\"><a title=\"(.*)\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"(.*)\">\s*(.*)\s*<\/a>&nbsp;<\/li>/m";
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);
```

the one i have right now doesnt seems to work

Comment: Oh no, the most dreaded question on SO!

Comment: @Hao: Have you seen this similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454

Answer (score 9):

Considering your are trying to extract some data from an **HTML string, regex are generally not the right/best tool** for the job.

Instead, why no use a **DOM parser**, like the **[`DOMDocument` class](http://www.php.net/domdocument)**, provided with PHP, and its [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) method ?

Then, you could navigate through your HTML document using DOM methods -- which is much easier than using regex, especially considering than HTML is not quite *regular*.

Here, for example, you could use something like this :

```
$html = <<<HTML
<li class="zk_list_c2 f_l"><a title="abc" target="_blank" href="link">
        abc
    </a>&nbsp;</li>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$as = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($as as $a) {
    var_dump($a->getAttribute('href'));
    var_dump(trim($a->nodeValue));
}
```

And you would get the following output :

```
string(4) "link"
string(3) "abc"
```

The code is not quite hard, I'd say, but, in a few words, here what it's doing :

- Load the HTML string : [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)
- Extract all `<a>` tags : [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)
- Foreach tag found :

  - get the `href` attribute : [`DOMElement::getAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php)
  - and the value of the node : [`DOMNode::$nodeValue`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue)

Just a note : you might want to check if the `href` attribute exists, with [`DOMElement::hasAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.hasattribute.php), before trying to use its value...

**EDIT after the comments :** here's a quick example using DOMXpath to get to the links ; I supposed you want the link that's inside the `<li>` tag with `class="zk_list_c2 f_l"` :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$as = $xpath->query('//li[@class="zk_list_c2 f_l"]/a');

foreach ($as as $a) {
    var_dump($a->getAttribute('href'));
    var_dump(trim($a->nodeValue));
}
```

And, again, you get :

```
string(4) "link"
string(3) "abc"
```

As you can see, the only thing that changes is the way you're using to get to the right `<a>` tag : instead of `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`, it's just a matter of :

- instanciating [The DOMXPath class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)
- and calling [`DOMXPath::query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) with the right XPath query.

Comment: There are more than one <li class="zk_list_c2 f_l"> I am trying to extract, so I cant really use DOMDocument class and the html is more complex than that.

Comment: @hao : then, maybe an XPath query, instead of getElementsByTagName, could do the trick ? *(see http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php )* ;; anyway, I would really not use regex for this kind of data-extraction.

Comment: You can set up a loop that goes over the array that DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName('li') returns, and extract the data using the above method IF (class == "zk_list_c2 f_l")

Comment: how would i only get the a tags inside of <li class="zk_list_c2 f_l">

$lis = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
foreach ($lis as $li) {
if($li->getAttribute('class')=="zk_list_c2 f_l")
{
     echo (trim($li->nodeValue))."<BR>";
}
this doesnt display the a tags inside, is there a way for me to extract everything inside of the li?

Comment: The `nodeValue` property only contains the content of the node (here, your `<li>` tag) itself, a not the content of its children -- to get the content of the `<a>` tag, you have to access it ;; I suppose you could do that with the `childNodes` property of your `$li`, to loop over the children of `<li>` ; but, if I had to choose, I would rather prefer Xpath -- I've edited my answer with an example.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Have fun ! *(and don't use regex to parse html ^^ )*